# Can I specify database in URI for elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Would this work?

.env:

`ELASTIC_SEARCH_URI=http://localhost:9200/example-dev`

The docs just say to use `ELASTIC_SEARCH_URI=http://localhost:9200/` but I have two different apps on same dedicated server using elasticsearch. I want to specify a unique database for each app.

```
const es = new ElasticsearchClient({
  node: "http://localhost:9200",
  /*
    auth: {
        username: 'elastic',
        password: 'password'
    }
    */
});
```

Comment: Can you please give more details ? diffrents apps means Elastic App Search or your custom application ? are you using java, python, js or which language ?

Comment: I'm using deno so typescript

Comment: can you put your sample code where you are reading `ELASTIC_SEARCH_URI` variable

Comment: updated original question.

Comment: can you please put code for query as well ? how you are executing query ?

Comment: I haven't written any queries yet. I'm just trying to instantiate the lib when the app starts handling a request.

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple instances of Elasticsearch you can create 2 different containers, one will listen to `:9200` and the other `:9201` for example.

If what you mean by `specifying database` is different index. Then you can encapsulate the necessary function to your needs.

```js
// search func in app 1
const esSearch = (body) => {
  const response = await es.search({
    target: "my-app1",
    body,
  });
}

// search func in app 2
const esSearch = (body) => {
  const response = await es.search({
    target: "my-app2",
    body,
  });
}
```

There is no specifying the database because Elasticsearch itself is a single database. You can create different indices for different data.

Comment: SO docker is the only way to segrate the app's ES instances?

Comment: No of course not, it's just easier with Docker. It's probably possible you to run 2 different Elasticsearch instances in your computer. You can find how with a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for two different apps:

**APP1**

Lets consider datsource name for APP1 is `example-dev`

```js
const es = new ElasticsearchClient({
  node: "http://localhost:9200",
  /*
    auth: {
        username: 'elastic',
        password: 'password'
    }
    */
});

const result = await es.search({
    index: 'example-dev',
    query: {
      match: {
        quote: 'winter'
      }
    }
  })
```

**APP2**

Lets consider datsource name for APP2 is `example-dev-app2`

```js
const es = new ElasticsearchClient({
  node: "http://localhost:9200",
  /*
    auth: {
        username: 'elastic',
        password: 'password'
    }
    */
});

const result = await es.search({
    index: 'example-dev-app2',
    query: {
      match: {
        quote: 'winter'
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: i was hoping i could specifiy it in the url but i guess not, also this is not ideal because i can't set the index at the start. I have to tell it anytime i use the search api

Comment: When you create client, at that time you can not specify index name in Easticsearch SDK. You need to sepcify when you do the query. So You can use dynemic param in your API for index name and based on that you can pass index name while doing query. @chovy

Comment: what would index be for then? can I have `<index>.posts` for example? or are these more like collections in mongodb. I'm just wondering if I'll only ever have one index for my app.

Comment: its more like table in SQL DB you can say.

Comment: So, first you can create elasticsearch client and then you can pass specific index name to retrive data from specific index only while query.

Comment: yeah this is kind of dangerous if you have two apps with a users index.

Comment: right but is your two apps using same elasticsearch or diffrent elasticsearch ?

Comment: its all on one server. both dev environment and production.